# Extend independent classes with a set of methods and attributes (wrapper)

Tags: python, python-3.x, software-design

My goal is to create a class which extends different classes with a set of functionality. 
In the code below I was able to create a solution to the problem, but to me it seems like this is not the way to do it.

Requirements: 
- The base classes (Cat, Dog) can not be changed. 
- The classes with the added functionality (Pet_Dog, Pet_Cat) should have minimum amount of code because I need a lot of them with only minor changes. 
- I need to be able to import the BaseClasses (Cat, Dog) as well as the enhanced class (Pet_Dog, Pet_Cat).

My "solution" so far:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = 4
        self.lives = 9

    def make_sound(self):
        print('Meow!')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = 4
        self.hobby = 'Digging holes'

    def make_sound(self):
        print('Woof!')

    def chase_tail(self):
        print('Chasing tail')

def create_pet(BaseClass):
    class Pet(BaseClass):
        has_owner = True
        def __init__(self, name, legs):
            super().__init__(legs)
            self.name = name

        def plays_with_owner(self):
            print('playing with owner...')
    return Pet


class Pet_Dog(Dog):
    def __init__(self, BaseClass, name, legs):
        self.__class__ = create_pet(BaseClass)(name, legs).__class__
        self.__init__(name, legs)


class Pet_Cat(Cat):
    def __init__(self, BaseClass, name, legs):
        self.__class__ = create_pet(BaseClass)(name, legs).__class__
        self.__init__(name, legs)


print('Create Pet Dog')
pet_dog = Pet_Dog(Dog, 'Woofer', 4)
print('Dog Name:', pet_dog.name)
print('Dog Lives:', pet_dog.hobby)
print('Dog Owner:', pet_dog.has_owner)
pet_dog.make_sound()
pet_dog.chase_tail()
pet_dog.plays_with_owner()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can have classes which inherit from multiple other classes, so we can make a `Cat`, and `Dog` class, as well as a separate `Pet` class. We can then make `Pet_Cat` and `Pet_Dog` inherit from both `Pet` and their respective animals, ie:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        self.lives = 9

    def make_sound(self):
        print('Meow!')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        self.hobby = 'Digging holes'

    def make_sound(self):
        print('Woof!')

    def chase_tail(self):
        print('Chasing tail')

class Pet:
    has_owner = True
    name = None

    def plays_with_owner(self):
        print('playing with owner...')

class Pet_Dog(Dog, Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        super().__init__(legs)
        self.name = name

class Pet_Cat(Cat, Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        super().__init__(legs)
        self.name = name


print('Create Pet Dog')
pet_dog = Pet_Dog('Woofer', 4)
print('Dog Name:', pet_dog.name)
print('Dog Lives:', pet_dog.hobby)
print('Dog Owner:', pet_dog.has_owner)
pet_dog.make_sound()
pet_dog.chase_tail()
pet_dog.plays_with_owner()
```

Output:

```
Create Pet Dog
Dog Name: Woofer
Dog Lives: Digging holes
Dog Owner: True
Woof!
Chasing tail
playing with owner...
```

**EDIT:**

Use this instead if you want init functions on both:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        self.lives = 9

    def make_sound(self):
        print('Meow!')

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        self.hobby = 'Digging holes'

    def make_sound(self):
        print('Woof!')

    def chase_tail(self):
        print('Chasing tail')

class Pet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.has_owner = True
        self.name = None

    def plays_with_owner(self):
        print('playing with owner...')

class Pet_Dog(Dog, Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        Dog.__init__(self, legs)
        Pet.__init__(self)

        self.name = name

class Pet_Cat(Cat, Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, legs):
        Cat.__init__(self, legs)
        Pet.__init__(self)

        self.name = name
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I tried it with multiple inheritance before, but than i got stuck with handling the two __init__ methods. Pet needs to have one, but it should be called after the one from the BaseClass. Is that possible with multiple inheritance?

Comment: There's a better way to handle the calls to the superclasses initializers, cf my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use inheritance here, you can use multiple inheritance and cooperative `super` call to avoid useless repetitions:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        self.lives = 9


class Dog:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = legs
        self.hobby = 'Digging holes'

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.has_owner = True
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def plays_with_owner(self):
        print('playing with owner...')


# Pet has to come before the "animal" class for the cooperative
# super() call to work

class PetCat(Pet, Cat):
    pass

class PetDog(Pet, Dog):
    pass
```

You can even automate the creation of those subclasses, but it's not necessarily an improvement:

```
def make_pet_class(name, base):
    return type.__new__(name, (Pet, base), {})

PetCat = make_pet_class("PetCat", Cat)
```

Now inheritance is not necessarily the best solution for everything. Inheritance is mostly a very restricted form of composition / delegation, and Python makes composition / delegation quite easy:

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, animal):
        self._animal  = animal
        self.name = name
        self.has_owner = True

    def plays_with_owner(self):
        print('playing with owner...')

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self._animal, attr)


kitty = Pet("kitty", Cat(4))
pluto = Pet("pluto", Dog(4))
```